# What data format is this? How to parse it?

Tags: javascript, bash, format

I get weather data from my sensors as a text file containing the below data format. I plan to extract only a number of data fields with either a Javascript or a bash script. I'm not sure what data format it is and is there any ready-made parsing module I can call by specifying the field name and get the corresponding value. For example, to get value 82.8 by specifying 'tempinf'

```
Array
(
    [PASSKEY] => F638EE7A02................
    [stationtype] => GW1000_V1.6.8
    [dateutc] => 2021-12-20 08:59:16
    [tempinf] => 82.8
    [humidityin] => 49
    [baromrelin] => 29.822
    [baromabsin] => 29.822
    [tempf] => 84.4
    [humidity] => 45
    [winddir] => 275
    [windspeedmph] => 0.00
    [windgustmph] => 0.00
    [maxdailygust] => 0.00
    [solarradiation] => 52.98
    [uv] => 1
    [rainratein] => 0.000
    [eventrainin] => 0.000
    [hourlyrainin] => 0.000
    [dailyrainin] => 0.000
    [weeklyrainin] => 0.000
    [monthlyrainin] => 0.000
    [yearlyrainin] => 38.185
    [totalrainin] => 38.185
    [wh65batt] => 0
    [wh26batt] => 0
    [freq] => 433M
    [model] => GW1000_Pro
)
```

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: That looks like [PHP's `print_r` output](https://www.php.net/print_r). If so, this is hardly readily parsable by anything, and is in fact not safe to parse, because it *can* be ambiguous.

Comment: _"I'm not sure what data format it is"_ - That's a topic for the documentation of your weather sensors

Comment: Looks like the printed output of an associative array in PHP.  I doubt there's a ready-made JavaScript library for parsing it.  If you can modify the code which *produces* this output, change it to output JSON instead.  Otherwise you're likely going to have to manually parse this.

Comment: And why is there a `bash` tag?

Comment: You could use [php-print_r-to-json](https://www.nestforms.com/php-print_r-to-json-online) (or write a converter yourself) and then use the JSON object instead.

Comment: This appears to be a display of a variable holding an array (probably with print_r() ).  It's difficult to help you without seeing the code that creates the array. The name of the array variable would also be helpful to people replying with examples.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a String representation of Php arrays. I would not bother finding the exact data standard, but rather parse it as it is using JS (or a language of choice). An easy way I see, is to split on `\n` (newlines) and the split on `=>` to get the `key` and `value`. Then you clean spaces for the value and remove `[...]` for the key. That should cover up most of cases you will ocur.

Comment: Thank you all. I managed to generate json formatted text file instead, with json_encode from source. Thus, easier to extract value.